# Software to find eigenvalues

Tags: math-software

Is there a software (or website) that is free which can find eigenvalues but with arbitrary constants, say $a,b>0$ being involved?

Comment: You could try [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com)

Comment: @GregordeCillia any ideas how to input something like that?

Comment: [This example](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?lk=3&i=%7B%7B0,-1%7D,%7B1,a%7D%7D) will get you started. It contains eigenvalues further down in the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use wolframalpha for that. The following input gives eigenvalues depending on parameters $a,b$:

```
eigenvalues {{4,a},{b,-1}}
```

Here a [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eigenvalues+%7B%7B4,a%7D,%7Bb,-1%7D%7D).